# How to Interop between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, interop

I'm attempting a very basic interoperation between the 2 languages. I basically have some performance intensive code I wanna handle in C++ and then get the result back to my application.

All is going to be compiled in Visual Studio.

i have chosen *int* to be the input and output type since marshalling can be a bit wonky and not really what i'm dealing with.

C++ i have:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // default from vs2013, no idea what it is

_declspec(dllexport) int Diu(int p) {
    return p * 2;
}
```

C# i have:

```
using System;

namespace Interop {
    public class Program{
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Hardworker.dll")]
        public static extern int Diu(int p);

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Diu(2));
        }
    }
}
```

So it's a pretty basic example. But I'm getting the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in Interop.exe
>
> Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

The C++ project is created as a Console Application > Dll in the create dialog.
I checked the C++ dll in the disassembler and i can see a *Diu* as an exported symbol.

Uh. What did I miss about the setting up interop?

Comment: (or future reader) In addition to taking care to match platform (x86 vs x64, native C++ doesn't support AnyCPU), and name mangling, take care to also match the calling convention between the C++ code and the p/invoke declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get this error: `HRESULT: 0x8007000B` is caused by platform incompatibility.
Check that that your compiler profile are set to the same platform(`x86`, `x64` or `AnyCPU`).

Comment: Nice. I my computer is x64. I set compile to x86. And the error changed to EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'Diu' in DLL 'Hardwork.dll'.

Comment: @CyberFox C++ mangles the function names based on parameter types, and other qualifiers of the function. You need to declare the function `extern "C"` for it to export with the name without mangling.

Comment: @YngveHammesrland that actually worked. 2 answers in 1.